# Symfony2 check user value for all routes

Tags: php, symfony

My project is Symfony2, and must before any function of a controller is called, I check to see if a user attribute has a value to continue.
Example:
- My User object has the "`business`" attribute to null or integer value;
- When he access any route other than the route named "`app_business`", check that the name attribute "`business`" user is null

> ($user->getBusiness() != null)

if null need to redirect it for "app_business" route;

How can I do this without having to add the "IF" on all routes?

Comment: Take a look at this article about `before` and `after` filters - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Comment: Or grant your users the ROLE_BUSINESS where the $user->getBusiness() !== null and secure your actions against this role.